# Hide app from tray in LXDE (Lubuntu)

Tags: lubuntu, panel, lxde, system-tray, lxpanel

In XFCE it is possible to hide app from tray, using tray settings (for example set steam not to appear in tray, using xfce settings). I need such a feature in Lubuntu, however LXPanel doesn't seem to have such a settings. But maybe there is some config file where I can put banned applications for systray?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

LXDE uses openbox as windowmanager

openbox has a config-file in
~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
(this is a simple text-file, so use an appropriate text-editor for changes, like vim)

this file has a -normaly- empty section called

....
....

but with an example of possible settings there.

I dont use steam, but to disable the appearance of xosview in the panel
and display it without window-decorations, i did add the following there:

```
<application name="xosview" title="xosview" type="normal" class="XOsview" role="">
  <decor>no</decor>
  <desktop>all</desktop>
  <focus>no</focus>
  <layer>below</layer>
  <!-- above, below -->
  <skip_pager>yes</skip_pager>
  <skip_taskbar>yes</skip_taskbar>
</application>
```

the entry for skip_pager and skip_taskbar may be whats necessary for the steam-program. You have to check the right program name, maybe look it up with lxtask.